# Practicing Singly Linked List implementation, stumped by my list reversal method throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

Here is my singly linked list code:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {

private static Node head;
private static int listSize;

private static class Node {

    int value;
    Node next;

    Node(int i) {
        value = i;
        next = null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    head = null;
    listSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Node n = new Node(i);
        if (head == null) {
            head = n;
        } else {
            getLastNode(head).next = n;
        }
        listSize++;
    }
    printNodeValues(head);
    Node revHead = reverseList(head);
    printNodeValues(revHead);
}

private static Node reverseList(Node head) {
    Node reverseHead = getLastNode(head);
    Node reference = reverseHead;
    while (listSize>0){
        Node temp = getPreviousNode(reference, head);
        Node last = getLastNode(reverseHead);
        temp.next = null;
        last.next = temp;
        reference = temp;
        listSize--;
    }
    return reverseHead;
}

private static Node getPreviousNode(Node reference, Node head) {
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.next == reference) {
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

private static Node getLastNode(Node n) {
    Node temp = n;
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp.next == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public static void printNodeValues(Node h) {
    while (h != null) {
        System.out.print(h.value + " ");
        h = h.next;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

The problem is with my reverseList(Node) method. When I run the program, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SinglyLinkedList.reverseList(SinglyLinkedList.java:44) -> temp = null;
at SinglyLinkedList.main(SinglyLinkedList.java:33) -> Node revHead = reverseList(head);
```

My printNodeValues works fine, and prints

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

and I'm trying to use reverseList to print

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0.

Comment: looks like you aren't updating `reverseHead` in the loop, but you're reassigning last to it, which doesn't look right to me

Comment: Have you heard about debuggers? Have you used one to debug your program?

Comment: Should your reverse method modify the list or return a new one ? I'm writing an answer and need this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many very bad things in your code. Worst of all : why is everything static ? What's the point of writing a list class that can be instantiated only once ?

Then, the size of the list should never be affected by a reverse operation, and you don't even need a counter since you just have to iterate over the list until you find a node which has no successor.

```
private static Node reverseList(Node head) {
    Node res = null;    
    while (head != null) {
        Node node = new Node(head.value);
        node.next = res;
        res       = node;
        head      = head.next;
    }    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I made everything static so that I wouldn't have to do SinglyLinkedList sll = new SinglyLinkedList(); this is just me trying to understand data structures

Comment: And why should you avoid that ? Constructors are the basis of OOP. Anyway, please look at the code, which is the canonical way to return the reverse of a list

Comment: @dici i feel the op wants to focus on the logic of how to reverse the linked list rather than focus on OOP

Comment: @KickButtowski my answer is meant to address both

Comment: @Dici thanks for the help! I'll avoid statics next time.

Comment: @KickButtowski you're right, I forgot to update the head

Answer (score 1):

Your `reverseList()` method needs to skip the iteration when it has reached the first node in the original list because it's previous node doesn't exist. This first node has already be assigned as the next node (i.e. the last node in the reversed list) in the second last iteration (of your original loop).

```
private static Node reverseList(Node head) {
    Node reverseHead = getLastNode(head);
    Node reference = reverseHead;

    int counter = listSize; 
    while ( counter > 1) {
        Node temp = getPreviousNode(reference, head);
        Node last = getLastNode(reverseHead);
        temp.next = null;
        last.next = temp;
        reference = temp;
        counter--;
    }
    return reverseHead;
}
```

Secondly, you shouldn't modify your `listSize` variable directly because the number of elements in the reversed list remains the same. Here, I'm storing it in a temporary `counter` first before iterating the list.

And, finally the reversed list should become your current `head`. Since, you've modified the linking between all the elements, it can only be traversed if your `head` now points to the new `head`.

```
printNodeValues(head);
head = reverseList(head);
printNodeValues(head);
```

Comment: Isn't the complexity of such implementation `O(n^2)` ?

Comment: I'm not proposing a new algorithm to OP. Just pointing out the bugs.

Comment: @Dici could you explain how you came up with O(n^2) ?

Comment: @KickButtowski n iterations performing a `O(n)` operation (`getLastNode`). Not only that, `getPreviousNode` is also `O(n)`. Yet, it is true that Ravi explains the OP why his code does not work whereas I don't. Maybe you should just mention the complexity and it would be a better answer than mine